# The term 'Rename-Computer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I want to rename the computer with PowerShell 2.0 in Windows 7 Sp1, but it got an error.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Rename-Computer -NewName PC02
The term 'Rename-Computer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script f
ile, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, ver
ify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ Rename-Computer <<<<  -NewName PC02
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Rename-Computer:String) [], CommandNotFo 
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `Rename-Computer` was introduced in Powershell 3.0

Comment: So how can I do, upgrade Powershell to 3.0 or use other cmdlet in 2.0 can do this?

Comment: @WeRubChan If you want to use `Rename-Computer`, you'll need to upgrade to v3 (and if possible, I recommend upgrading). Otherwise [here](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/922.aspx) is a method to rename in v2.

Comment: It *is* possible in PowerShell 2, using WMI. See the answer I just added.

Comment: @AdiInbar I know - which is why I had included a method using WMI in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in PowerShell 2.0, use WMI:

```powershell
(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Rename('PC02')
```

You can rename a remote computer by adding `-ComputerName CURRENTNAME` after **Get-WmiObject**.

You must do this from an elevated prompt. This will, of course, require a reboot to take effect.